# How many cigarettes can I bring back from Serbia to the European Union?

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, eu, serbia, smoking

I am going to Serbia this summer and I would like to know how many cigarettes I can bring back to the European Union.

P.S I am going from Serbia to Latvia through Frankfurt (Germany) by plane.

Comment: I think it DOES vary from country to country. So you have to say which countr(y)(ies) of the EU you want to go in/through to get an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it may vary from country to country, but usually you're allowed to bring 200 cigattes.

From [europa.eu](http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/common/travellers/enter_eu/index_en.htm):

> Each Member State decides on the limit applicable:
>
> - **200 cigarettes** or 40 cigarettes;*
> - 100 cigarillos or 20 cigarillos; *
> - 50 cigars or 10 cigars; *
> - 250 grams of tobacco or 50 g smoking tobacco*
>
> *Each amount represents 100% of the total allowance for tobacco products and any combination of those products must not exceed 100%.
>   Example: 100 cigarettes + 50 cigarillos = total allowance

[The website of the German customs administration](http://www.zoll.de/EN/Private-individuals/Travel/Entering-Germany/Duties-and-taxes/Travellers-allowances/travellers-allowances_node.html) confirms that 200 cigarettes can be brought into Germany tax/duty-free.

Comment: Am I the only one who's confused about: **200 cigarettes or 40 cigarettes**....

Comment: @Karlson As far as I understand it some countries allow 200 cigarettes and other only 40.

Comment: Shweet!!!  Let's add to the confusion. :)

Comment: +1 Member states can indeed choose between the lower and higher thresholds (but not set an arbitrary threshold), as explained in article 8 of the [directive mentioned on the page](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2007:346:0006:0012:EN:PDF).

Comment: Where can you find if a given country allows 200 or 40 cigarettes?